# Help me safely mod my freezer

Tags: energy-efficiency, electricity, life-cycle-analysis, cooling, food-storage

I want to connect my freezer to an external thermostat like this to maintain a higher temperature than it otherwise could. Are there any thermostats or other control devices that would keep the freezer compressor from cycling on and off too often?

(I intend to keep it at around 30 deg F to 50 deg F, or -1 to 10 deg C. I haven't bought the freezer yet but it will probably be an [Avanti CF24Q0W](https://www.avantiproducts.com/products/id/733)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that some of these thermostats have "compressor delay protection," such as this one: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01HXM5UAC/?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HXM5UAC)